# Calling a C function in a pro*C file

Tags: c++, extern

I have these line in my pro*C program. The function initAverage(int i) is defined in a C language and I am trying to call this function in a .pcc (Pro C++) file.

I am getting an error

```
Error: initAverage(int i);was declared before with a different language

extern "C"
{
int initAverage(int i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an include before that already declares `initAverage` without `extern "C"`. Look at all declarations of `initAverage` and fix the missing `extern` declaration then it should be fine.

PS:
Adding the [calling convention](http://www.color-of-code.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=72:calling-conventions&catid=45:programming&Itemid=68) explicitly is a good idea in general. I would add that too (while not being actually part of the question)

Comment: Please have a look at the error statement initAverage(int i);was declared before with a different language.
It says the function is declared but in a different language

Comment: if `extern "C"` is missing it is NOT C anymore but the default language (C++/Pro C++?) so add `extern "C"` everywhere in the definition and declaration.